# Meu case 3 não exclui da lista e o case 4 não compara e retorna a quantidade de gênero escrito

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

Cadastro alguns livros, após isso tento excluir algum com meu case 3, mas digitando o case 2 para mostrar todos ele continua mostrando o livro que deveria ter sido excluído.
Meu case 4 deveria comparar a String  genero digitada com a String genero da classe Livro de cada lista, mas ele sempre retorna o valor ZERO no meu count como se não tivesse nenhuma String igual ... Segue meu código principal e o objeto abaixo.

```
package application;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import entities.Livro;

    public class Program {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Livro livroLivraria;
            List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();

            int count = 0;

            System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar Livro\n2 - Listar \n3 - Excluir Livro\n4 - Pesquisar Livro pelo gênero\n"
                    + "5 - Pesquisar Livro por faixa de preço\n6 - Calcular Total do Acervo\n7 - Sair\n");

            int opcao = sc.nextInt();

            do {
                switch(opcao) {
                    case 1 :    System.out.print("Quantos livros quer cadastrar ? ");
                                int j = sc.nextInt();
                                sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i=1; i <= j; i++) {
                                    System.out.println("LIVRO " + i);
                                    System.out.print("Nome: ");
                                    String nome = sc.nextLine();
                                    System.out.print("Autor: ");
                                    String autor = sc.nextLine();
                                    System.out.print("Gênero: ");
                                    String genero = sc.nextLine();
                                    System.out.print("Preço: ");
                                    Double preco = sc.nextDouble();
                                    sc.nextLine();
                                    livroLivraria = new Livro(nome, autor, genero, preco);
                                    livros.add(livroLivraria);
                                }
                                break;

                    case 2 :    for (Livro l : livros) {
                                    System.out.println(l);
                                }
                                break;

                    case 3 :    System.out.print("Qual nome do livro que deseja excluir ? ");
                                String nome = sc.nextLine();
                                sc.nextLine();

                                for (Livro l : livros) {
                                    if (l.getNome().equals(nome)) {
                                        livros.remove(l);
                                    }
                                }

                                System.out.println("Livro excluído...");
                                break;

                    case 4 :    System.out.print("Qual gênero procura ? ");
                                String genero = sc.nextLine();
                                sc.nextLine();

                                count = 0;
                                for(Livro l : livros) {
                                    if (l.getGenero().equals(genero)) {
                                        count++;
                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.println(count + " livros do gênero " + genero);

                                break;

                    case 5 :    System.out.print("Digite o valor inicial: ");
                                double p1 = sc.nextDouble();
                                System.out.print("Digite o valor final: ");
                                double p2 = sc.nextDouble();

                                count = 0;
                                if (p1 < p2) {
                                    for(Livro l : livros) {
                                        if (l.getPreco() >= p1 && l.getPreco() <= p2) {
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(count + " livros entre os valores R$" + p1 + " e R$" + p2);
                                }else {
                                    System.out.println("ERRO: valor inicial maior que valor final...");
                                }

                                break;

                    case 6 :    double t=0;
                                for (Livro l : livros) {
                                    t += l.getPreco();
                                }
                                System.out.println("Valor total dos livros R$" + t);

                                break;

                    case 7 : break;

                    default :   System.out.println("Esta opção não existe...");
                                break;
                }

                System.out.println("\n1 - Cadastrar Livro\n2 - Listar \n3 - Excluir Livro\n4 - Pesquisar Livro pelo gênero\n"
                        + "5 - Pesquisar Livro por faixa de preço\n6 - Calcular Total do Acervo\n7 - Sair\n");

                opcao = sc.nextInt();

            }while(opcao != 7);

            sc.close(); 
        }
    }
```

Classe objeto Livro:

```
package entities;

public class Livro {

    private String nome;
    private String autor;
    private String genero;
    private Double preco;

    public Livro(String nome, String autor, String genero, Double preco) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public Double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(Double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Livro [ Nome = " + nome + ", Autor = " + autor + ", Genero = " + genero + ", Preço = " + preco + " ]";
    }

}
```

Como eu resolveria isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que ocorre é que no seu **Case 3**, no trecho:

```
System.out.print("Qual nome do livro que deseja excluir ? ");
                                String nome = sc.nextLine();
                                sc.nextLine();
```

Você chama o sc.nextLine() para a String nome,  depois você anula chamando novamente o sc.nextLine(). Apenas invertendo as chamadas, o problema já não ocorre mais. É o mesmo caso para os outros cases.

```
System.out.print("Qual nome do livro que deseja excluir ? ");
                sc.nextLine();
                String nome = sc.nextLine();
```

Dê uma estudada sobre a classe Scanner e sobre imutabilidade.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou no case 4, mas o 3 dá o seguinte erro após eu digitar o nome do livro que desejo excluir: 

Qual nome do livro que deseja excluir ? HP2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)
 at application.Program.main(Program.java:54)